# Post request to a RestAPI giving me a null response using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I want to send POST request to a RestAPI using RestTemplate. When I execute below code, It give's me null response. But, I'm getting http status code 200 OK.
I have added response model properly, so there is no problem with model. Even, It doesn't give me a response when I change the response type to String. Any suggestions please?

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
               headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + "c21sOnBhc3N3b3Jk");
               headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");

               RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
               restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

               HttpEntity<NikeIdgenReq> request = new HttpEntity<NikeIdgenReq>(nikeIdgenReq, headers);

               String resp = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, String.class);
```

Comment: Any suggestions please......

Comment: You're making a POST request, so the response is configured in the method of the API that gets called. If it's your own method, add `@ResponseBody` for example. If it's an external API, there simply is no response configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling I have found a solution, I have made the response model class serializable 
and add JsonProperty annotations like in the below code

```
public class NikeIdgenRes implements Serializable{

    @JsonProperty("bundleID")
    private String bundleID;
    @JsonProperty("ids")
    private List<Id> ids = null;
    @JsonProperty("gtin")
    private String gtin;
    @JsonProperty("quantity")
    private Integer quantity;
    @JsonProperty("types")
    private List<String> types = null;
    @JsonProperty("meta")
    private Meta meta;

    // getters & setters
    }

public NikeIdgenRes addNikeIdgen(NikeIdgenRq nikeIdgenRq) { 

            String url = "https://idgen-dev.connected-product.edflab.nikecloud.net/sensors/id_bundle/v1";

            HttpEntity<NikeIdgenRq> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(nikeIdgenRq, getHttpHeaders());
            ResponseEntity<NikeIdgenRes> result = restTemplateBuilder.build().postForEntity(url, httpEntity, NikeIdgenRes.class);

            NikeIdgenRes nikeIdgenRes = new NikeIdgenRes();
            nikeIdgenRes.setBundleID(result.getBody().getBundleID());
            nikeIdgenRes.setIds(result.getBody().getIds());
            nikeIdgenRes.setGtin(result.getBody().getGtin());
            nikeIdgenRes.setQuantity(result.getBody().getQuantity());
            nikeIdgenRes.setTypes(result.getBody().getTypes());
            nikeIdgenRes.setMeta(result.getBody().getMeta());

           return nikeIdgenRes;
       }
```